# Trying to obtain a numeric solution to an inequality. Code might be not working as intended

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, code-review, inequalities

I need to check whether an inequality can have solutions in the real numbers, given some extra constraints on the variables. I suspect that no solutions exist but I would like some verification of that claim. My code is the following:

```
ineq := {(2/9) * (l1 + l2 + l3)^2 > RankedMax[
  Eigenvalues[
   Transpose[{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, t2, 
       t3 + l3}}].{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, 
      t2, t3 + l3}}], 1] + 
 RankedMax[
  Eigenvalues[
   Transpose[{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, t2, 
       t3 + l3}}].{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, 
      t2, t3 + l3}}], 2]};
con1 = {1 >= l1 >= -1};
con2 = {1 >= l2 >= - 1};
con3 = {1 >= l3 >= -1};
```

In practice I have four more constraints on the $t_i$ and $\lambda_i$ but to keep things simple I have omitted them. Now, since I am not optimistic that the Reduce command could track the problem, I use NSolve instead. It would be great if I can find even one solution to this inequality and not a general characterisation of the solutions, if they exist (I doubt it). Thus, I run the command:

```
NSolve[{ineq[[1]], con1[[1]], con2[[1]], con3[[1]]}, {l1, l2, l3, t1, t2,t3}]
```

However the program runs forever and even if I simplify it by letting the $t_i$ be equal to zero, in which case I know there are no solutions to the inequality by a slightly different analysis, I still get no quick answer. I try the simple case with the following command:

```
NSolve[{ineq[[1]], con1[[1]], con2[[1]], con3[[1]], t1 == 0, t2 == 0, 
t3 == 0}, {l1, l2, l3}]
```

This makes me think that my code is not very good and I am wondering if there is something that can be done to make this actually work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that when the solver options are behaving incredibly slowly, the local minimizers and maximizers (`FindMinimum` and `FindMaximum`) can help. We just have to rewrite the system a little bit. This is based on the question as it was originally posted, but this approach can prove helpful to try to quickly find a solution if it exists:

```
lhs = (2/9)*(l1 + l2 + l3)^2;
rhs = RankedMax[
     Eigenvalues[
      Transpose[{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, t2, 
          t3 + l3}}].{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, 
         t2, t3 + l3}}], 1]^2 + 
   RankedMax[
     Eigenvalues[
      Transpose[{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, t2, 
          t3 + l3}}].{{t1 + l1, t2, t3}, {-t1, -t2 - l2, -t3}, {t1, 
         t2, t3 + l3}}], 2]^2;
```

First, to simplify the manipulation of the inequality, I separated the left and right hand sides. We want to see if we can find a scenario where `lhs > rhs`, which is the same as finding a scenario where `lhs - rhs > 0`. I declare the constraints and the final system as follows:

```
constraints = {1 >= l1 >= -1, 1 >= l2 > -1, 1 >= l3 >= -1};
sys = {lhs - rhs, Sequence @@ constraints};
```

We can use `FindMaximum` to try to maximize `lhs - rhs`, and see if we can find a maximum greater than 0. I try the local maximizer first because if a solution exists it will probably be found rather quickly, but if we are trying to prove that a solution does not exist we would need to use a global maximizer, such as `Maximize`.

```
max = FindMaximum[
  sys, {{t1, 1/2}, {l1, 1/2}, {t2, 1/2}, {l2, 1/2}, {t3, 1/2}, {l3, 1/2}}]
```

> {0.327656, {t1 -> 0.0129505, l1 -> 0.863786, t2 -> -0.0120477, l2 -> 0.90072, t3 -> -0.0139592, l3 -> 0.904819}}

The maximum value found is greater than 0 (0.327656), and the it provides a sensible set of parameters to achieve that maxima. However, let's check that it satisfies the original inequality and the constraints:

```
{lhs > rhs, constraints} /. max[[2]]
```

> {True, {True, True, True}}

Thus, by example, this inequality does have at least one solution.

Unfortunately, this approach does not find a clear cut solution for the updated question using `FindMaximum` or `NMaximize`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! Then, apologies but I found some mistakes on the posted code: I had extra squares on the RankedMax's. After fixing this and running your code again, I get the following answer: 
    
    {-1.28856*10^-15, {t1 -> 0.0000500457, l1 -> -0.000292867, t2 -> 0.0000500457, l2 -> -0.000292867, t3 -> 0.0000500492, l3 -> -0.000292906}}

Does this, in your opinion, demonstrate that maybe no solutions exist?

Comment: Assuming this is the case, how can I modify your code so that I can try to get an exact answer (e.g. using Reduce or Solve) to whether this inequality can ever be fulfilled?

Comment: `FindMaximum` is a local solver, so it's not sufficient proof that there are no solutions. `NMaximize` is a global solver, but it is numerical in nature, so it's not airtight proof that there is no solution. `Maximize` is a global symbolic solver, but probably won't be any faster than `Solve` or `Reduce` here. This approach isn't easily modifiable to prove the non-existence of a solution, sorry. This won't make `Solve` or `Reduce` any faster here either. With the unedited question it was easy to show that there was at least one solution, but your problem's a lot harder now.

Comment: I see. That was my suspicion too. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help! I definitely got something from your answer, so if there are no answers that completely solve my problem soon, I will accept yours.